# How to add onclick property to multiple buttons using DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom, button, onclick

I am trying to add onclick properties to multiple buttons using DOM. `langButton.onclick = searchEngine(langButton);` does not add the property to the button and eventListener does not work either. I need to read the text of the specific button that is clicked, or just copy the button all together. Here is the code block:

```
for (j = 0; j < applications[i].languages.length; j++) {
  let langButton = document.createElement('button');
  langButton.classList.add('btn-secondary');
  langButton.innerHTML = `${applications[i].languages[j]}`;
  langButton.onclick = searchEngine(langButton);
  // console.log(langButton.innerHTML);
  langDiv.appendChild(langButton);
}
```

btn-secondary is a Bootstrap class.

```
function searchEngine(button) {
  return button
}
```

returns the button, but runs each time it tries to set the onclick property. Then the buttons do not return anything after being clicked. The `console.log(langButton.innerHTML)` returns the button's text just fine.

Comment: `onclick` expects a function; `searchEngine(langButton)` isn’t a function. Also, use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: The line `langButton.innerHTML = \`${applications[i].languages[j]}\`` can be shortened to langButton.innerHTML = applications[i].languages[j]

Answer (score 1):

An event listener has to be a function. You're calling the function, not assigning the function.

```
langButton.addEventListener("click", () => searchEngine(langButton));
```